# How can I return a stored procedure's result as XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I coded a web service connecting to MS-Sql server and getting the results from a stored procedure. My below code is getting only the first result of procedure, but I need all results in the response xml file. I think that I need to use data adapter, data reader, data fill, etc.. something like this. But I could not succeed. I would appreciate any help:

PS: Info.cs class already created.

```
[WebMethod]
public Info NumberSearch2(string no)
{
    Info ourInfo = new Info();
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBBaglan"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText: "NumberSearch", connection: Con)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };

        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@no",
            Value = no
        };

        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        Con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ourInfo.PartNo = dr["PartNo"].ToString();
            ourInfo.BrandNo = dr["BrandNo"].ToString();
            ourInfo.Manufacturer = dr["Manufacturer"].ToString();
            ourInfo.Country = dr["Country"].ToString();
            ourInfo.ReferenceNo = dr["ReferenceNo"].ToString();
        }
    }

    return ourInfo;
}
```

After @David 's recommendation:

```
    [WebMethod]
    //public Info NumberSearch2(string no)
    public List<Info> NumberSearch2(string no)
    {
        Info ourInfo = new Info();
        var ourInfos = new List<Info>();

        string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBBaglan"].ConnectionString;
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText: "NumberSearch", connection: Con)
            {
                CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter parameter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@no",
                Value = no
            };

            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            Con.Open();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            while (dr.Read())

            {
                var ourInfos = new Info();
                ourInfo.PartNo = dr["PartNo"].ToString();
                ourInfo.BrandNo = dr["BrandNo"].ToString();
                ourInfo.Manufacturer = dr["Manufacturer"].ToString();
                ourInfo.Country = dr["Country"].ToString();
                ourInfo.ReferenceNo = dr["ReferenceNo"].ToString();
                ourInfos.Add(ourInfo);
            }
        }

        return ourInfos;

    }
```

Comment: you are overwriting ourInfo again and again

Comment: Think about what you're doing. It doesn't logically make sense. You create a single `Info` object, and return it. You're overwriting the object's values with each record, meaning you're only going to return the last result. If you want to return multiple results, you need to return a collection of Info objects, declare a new Info object for each record (in your while loop) and add it to the collection.

Comment: Should you not be creating a list based on the ourInfo class, and then adding each read from the reader to the list, then return the list with all the records added?

Comment: The title and text have nothing to do with each other. Web services *already* convert their return values to XML. You don't have to do anything. Just define the *correct* return type, fill the appropriate object and return it. What you do here though, just overwrites the same value. Only the last object will be sent to the client

Comment: If you want to return an array of objects, change your return type to `Info[]` and create a *new* `Info` object in each loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning a single `Info` object.  If you want a collection of them, return a `List<Info>` instead.  Change the method signature:

```
public List<Info> NumberSearch2(string no)
```

Declare the object to return:

```
var ourInfos = new List<Info>();
```

Within your loop, add each record to the list:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    var ourInfo = new Info();
    ourInfo.PartNo = dr["PartNo"].ToString();
    ourInfo.BrandNo = dr["BrandNo"].ToString();
    ourInfo.Manufacturer = dr["Manufacturer"].ToString();
    ourInfo.Country = dr["Country"].ToString();
    ourInfo.ReferenceNo = dr["ReferenceNo"].ToString();
    ourInfos.Add(ourInfo);
}
```

And return the list:

```
return ourInfos;
```

Comment: Hi @David , thank you very much. It seems I am closer to the success. var ourInfos = new Info(); statement could not be recognized, and, I got 207 results (this is correct) of the same record (last record). Can you have a look once more?

Comment: @Murat: Have a look at *what*, exactly?  If you have updated code, include it in the question.  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code you're not showing.

Comment: Sorry @David, I added the code now below the original post.

Comment: @Murat: You're declaring the `ourInfo` object outside of the loop.  As suggested in this answer, declare it *inside* the loop.  You're also trying to re-declare a different `ourInfos` object inside the loop.  Don't do that.  The `ourInfos` object already exists.  The concept here is simple... Declare a list, loop over the records adding them to the list, return the list.